# Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf:

Tags: amazon-ec2, httpd

I installed mod_security and mod_evasive in the Amazon EC2. Initially it needs the components libxml2 libxml2-devel, httpd-devel, pcre-devel, curl-devel. But my site uses PHP56, so I used the following commands:

yum remove httpd-tools
yum -y install httpd24
yum -y install php56

and restarted the service httpd
the following message is displayed:

```
Stopping httpd: [FAILED]
Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf:
Invalid command 'SecRuleEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[FAILED]
```

I can not start the service, someone help me?

The file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf`

[image]

Comment: It doesn't come with `httpd24`. Try `yum install mod_security`.

Comment: Yes, i need httpd24 for run php 5.6. My problem is start service httpd.

Comment: From the looks of it, `httpd` won't start because you have `mod_security` configuration settings but no `mod_security` to make them work. Install `mod_security`. If you've already installed it, remove it and re-install it so it gets added to your new `httpd24` install.